# Prevent Checkbox un/check in DataGridView from being toggled automatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a column checkbox

[image]

What I want is if a checkbox click (i use CellContentClick Event)
I want show a messageBox that if user press ok .. then checkbox is checked and new query start. Else press Annul or Close Messagebox -> unchecked checkbox .

But I have a problem to implement it:

```
private void dgvApprovazione_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            if (dgvApprovazione.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            {
                CheckBox checkboxTmp = sender as CheckBox;

                checkboxTmp.AutoCheck = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

**EDIT**: I haven't access to design windows. Checkbox is a dynamic column that is result of read DB.

Column in the database is a true/false type .. In datagridview I have a checkbox with check or uncheck.

I want capture and prevent autocheck in 'code-time'

Comment: Sorry, now i'm specification ..... I'havent  access at design time ... Because checkbox is a db result about a field (true/false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the column read only at start up or when you add the column using [`ReadOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.readonly?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of the column, then handle [`CelllContentClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and show the message box and set the value of cell based on message box result:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load data
    //Add columns

    //I suppose your desired coulmn is at index 0
    this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //I suppose your desired coulmn is at index 0
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Check Item?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
        if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            ((DataGridView)sender)[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ((DataGridView)sender)[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = false;
        }
    }
}
```

There is not a real `CheckBox` in the cell and the sender of event is `DataGridView`.

Comment: Based on your previous question, you may need to check if the clicked cell doesn't belongs to the new row: using `e.RowIndex!=dataGridView1.newRowIndex`

Comment: In case of my checkbox it is already checked, this strategy doesn't prevent the auto-check or uncheck. 
But work good when uncheck... 
i'want make readonly checkbox when is checked.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your checkbox is checked or not. The job that we are doing here is **1-** Making the Cell read only. So you can't check or uncheck it manually. **2-** Handling `CellContentClick` and putting a logic there to provide a logic to check or uncheck. **So** You can have any logic here. For example you can set value = !value if you want to toggle item check or any other logic.

Comment: True! I'm sorry.. 
on Monday I'm still confused by the Saturday night ( Sunday morning )..
lol :D 
Thanks!

Comment: I've been struggling for 3 days trying to figure out how to use DataGridView's builtin checkbox support as a "radio button" which allows one and only one row to be selected at a time. (All rows unchecked is an illegal state.) This is the cleanest, simplest, most elegant solution without writing a custom control. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, glad that it helped. You may want to [Draw RadioButton instead of CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808205/3110834).